# transferring contacts

Tags: contacts

I have a new HTC Wildfire S phone and have tried to copy the contacts off my old phone which is a Samsung E250E.

I have the Bluetooth activated on old phone but 'Transfer data' app on new phone fails each time I attempt transfer by telling me my old phone is 'unsupported'.

Sim cards are different sizes so can't just plug old card into new phone, has anyone found a way of dealing with this, please?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a PC cable for your SGH E250 you could try Mobile Master management software for feature phones. It has a 30 day full working trial (download at http://www.mobile-master.com/samsung/sgh_e250.html ). MM supports many different phone models and allows to export contacts to .vcard or .csv format.

Samsung also offers sync software but I found that newer versions often have problems with discontinued phone models. You might give it a try if MM does not work for you.

A) You then can import that .vcard into gmail.com's contact application. Your HTC Wildfire will then sync them once you registered the phone with your GMail Account

B) You can also push the .vcard to your HTC and import it from there. You will be promted to import when you try to open the vcard. All recent Android models allow that.

Last resort: If all that is not possible (I had to do that already once), you're maybe best off by using GMail's Web frontend to manually input your contacts one by one instead of doing it on the phone.

In case you have an old Sony Ericsson model that supports the old sim format of your SGH E250: These usually allow to export phone contacts to vCard format onto the memory stick. You could then just go ahead with A) or B).

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to pair the devices via bluetooth, the go to your old phone's contact list and either go through the menus to find a `Select all` option, or go through your contacts one by one and select `Send` (or `Share`) -> `Bluetooth` -> `<your new phone>`. They will appear on your new phone as vCards and you can save them, but I think you have to do this one by one on the new phone (I might be wrong, I have no experience with HTC phones).

Comment: And thats not something I've tried so will give this a go and see what happens.